How can I get previous/next value if their is a match?
I have an SQL table that provides "GGATEVISITNUMBER", "SUB_TYPE", and a time context field (date/time).
Every row is unique but a GATEVISITNUMBER can have multiple SUB_TYPEs.
| GATEVISITNUMBER | SUB_TYPE |  TIME     |
| --------        | -------- |           |
| 98553336        | RM       |   6:03 am |
| 98553336        | DI       |   6:20 am |

What I want to achieve is for every unique GATEVISITNUMBER what was the first sub_type and the sub_type that followed after.
For the above example, GATEVISITNUMBER 98553336 was a RM then DI.
The issue is in SQL when I use lag(), it pulls the previous sub_type even if it is a different GATEVISITNUMBER. So if GATEVISITNUMBER 12345678 only has 1 sub_type, lag() is extracting GATEVISITINUMBER 98553336 sub_type which is incorrect.
The logic I need:
If GATEVISITNUMBER has more than 1 SUB_TYPE, than give me the first sub_type and the sub_type followed after. Else if GATEVISITNUMBER only has 1 entry than the second sub_type field should be null
| GATEVISITNUMBER | SUB_TYPE |  SUB_TYPE2|
| --------        | -------- |           |
| 98553336        | RM       |   DI      |
| 12345678        | DI       |  null     |

I tried using LAG and JOIN

When you say 'first' and 'that followed after', do you mean that the records would be ordered by time? What happens after midnight? Is there some other column that has an actual timestamp, or is the table guaranteed to be ordered by time by default and is the TIME column really superfluous?

additionally, please share the actual code you are running, also a few more rows of data would not go amiss, what db (name/version) and OS are you using. tks

Like Grismar noted, you have an ordering issue, if the same GATEVISITNUMBER can occur on more than one day.
Beside that, you can use group by and an aggregation function depending on your DBMS
MySQL example:
SELECT GATEVISITNUMBER,
       group_concat(SUB_TYPE ORDER BY TIME LIMIT 1 OFFSET 0) AS SUB_TYPE_1,
       group_concat(SUB_TYPE ORDER BY TIME LIMIT 1 OFFSET 1) AS SUB_TYPE_2
FROM your_table
GROUP BY GATEVISITNUMBER;

In SQL Server or PostgreSQL you may use string_agg instead of group_concat. In Other SQL-dialects, look for equivalent functions
